# Write an algorithm to list all the bits of length of to 20 with no consecutive 1's

Tags: recursion, bit

I'm thinking of doing a for loop starting along the lines of:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 20, i++){ 


    if i = 1; 


       i --;
```

` 
and then I'm running trouble when considering the case when i = 0. There's 2 possible cases, i.e., print i = 0, or print i = 1.
I can see that this is going to be defined recursively, i.e., each bit is defined based on the previous digits.

Comment: I think, `FFFFFFFF` is 20 one you need all numbers those are not in `FFFFFFFF << i  for i =0 to 11` for 32 bit number

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit? Show an example? I didn't get it.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623242/algorithm-recursion-or-loop but that one doesn't have an answer. It does have a hint in a comment, though :)

Answer (score 0):

I did not clearly understand your question, but I guessed, you want to get "all integers from 1 to (1<<20), with no blocks like 11 or 111 or 111, etc".

If so, this is the code:

```
for(int m = 0x55555; m <= 0xAAAAA; m <<= 1) {
  int x = m;
  do {
    printf("x=0x%05x\n", x);
  } while(x = (x - 1) & m);
}
```

Comment: I want to print out all the possible combinations of 1's and 0's with anywhere to 1 bit to 20 bits and with there being no consecutive ones. For example:

100100101 would work but 
1100000000000000000

Comment: Provided code does this. It just print in hex format, not binary. I think, binary print you can write yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it well, you want to generate every 20 bit pattern which does not contain consecutive 1's. For example, `00000000000000000001` is valid, but `00000000000000000011` is not.

This is a naturally recursive problem. You can think of it like a tree where each node is either a 1 or a 0. Nodes that are a 1 can only have one child (a 0 bit), and nodes that are 0 have 2 childs, because after a 0 there can be another 0. Pictorially, it works like this:

[image: Bits tree]

The tree expands like that until we hit a depth of 20. I'll call this value `CUTOFF`, since you may want to change it in the future. The idea behind the code is precisely the idea conveyed by the tree:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define CUTOFF 20

char buffer[CUTOFF+1];

void print_bits(char next_bit, unsigned char count) {
    buffer[count] = next_bit + '0';
    if (count == CUTOFF-1) {
        buffer[CUTOFF] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        return;
    }
    print_bits(!next_bit, count+1);
    if (next_bit == 0)
        print_bits(next_bit, count+1);
}
```

We keep a buffer with the bit string because we need to print it more than once for the case that `next_bit == 0`. The buffer is a way to know the path from the root to the current node, and each node can only write in the position corresponding to its depth (tracked by `count`).

You can start the party with:

```
int main(void) {
    print_bits(0, 0);
    print_bits(1, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

For very large values of `CUTOFF` (greater than 255), you may want to change `count` from `unsigned char` to `int`.

Note that this code will, by definition, find `00000000000000000000` to be a valid entry. If you want to always have at least a 1, you have to ignore this case. You can test for it using `strcmp()` in the base case of the recursion, but that would be inefficient. Another possible approach is to keep a counter of how many ones you have written, and test its value in the base case (or just use a flag to indicate if there has been at least a "1" written).